# Find and replace in word doc using VBA "invalid outside procedure"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have to put the same text into several different Word templates and copying and pasting it over and over is quite tedious. So I'm trying to make something that will replace words (the words in << >>) in a word doc with whatever I put into an Excel cell. I've tried the following but keep getting the error "invalid outside procedure", I'm not sure why as from what I can find online this error is due to not assigning a value to a variable when Option Explicit is used, but I'm not using that.

ETA: I added

```
End With
r = r + 1
Loop
```

after `.Application.Selection.EndOf` based on the answers here, but it's still giving me the same error

Edit 2: I moved the `End With` and `Loop` to the end and it'd still giving the error

```
Sub ReplaceText()
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wdoc As Word.Document
Dim custN, path As String
Dim r As Long
r = 2
Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) <> ""

    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    wApp.Visible = True
    
    Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="\\desktop\file.dotx", ReadOnly:=True)
    
    With wdoc
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<blue>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 2).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<red>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 3).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<yellow>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
    
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<green>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 5).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
        
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<white>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 6).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
        
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<grey>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 7).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
        
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<black>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 8).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
        
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<mauve>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 9).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
        
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<purple>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 10).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
        
        .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "<<beige>>"
        .Application.Selection.Find.Execute
        .Application.Selection = Sheet1.Cells(r, 11).Value
        .Application.Selection.EndOf
        
custN = Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value
path = "\\desktop"
.SaveAs2 Filename:=path & custN, _
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
   
End With
r = r + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: you missed the closing "With wdoc".    put a "End With"  after .Application.Selection.EndOf

Comment: You're missing an `End With` and a `Loop` but otherwise that complies fine No "invalid outside procedure", so there's something else you've not included in your post.

Comment: btw, `wdoc.Application.Selection` is same as `wApp.Selection` in your code.

Comment: Looks like  you added the End With/Loop in the wrong place?   "invalid outside procedure" means you have executable code (something other than an `Option` statement or a declaration) outside of a Sub/Function - VBA doesn't allow that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-outside-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using the next adapted, more compact code. Of course, the workbook must have a reference to 'Microsoft Word x.x Object Library':

```
Sub ReplaceText()
 Dim wApp As Word.Application, wdoc As Word.Document
 Dim custN, path As String, arrWords, oRng As Word.Range, sh1 As Worksheet
 Dim r As Long, i As Long
 Const templateName As String = "\\desktop\file.dotx"
 path = "\\desktop\" 'Please, take care of the ending backslash 
                     '(if it does not exist in the A:A column where from the doc name is taken)
 
 r = 2

 Set sh1 = ActiveSheet 'Sheet1
 arrWords = Array("<<blue>>", "<<red>>", "<<yellow>>", "<<green>>", "<<white>>", _
                  "<<grey>>", "<<black>>", "<<mauve>>", "<<purple>>", "<<beige>>")
 
 Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 wApp.Visible = True

 Do While sh1.cells(r, 1) <> ""
    Set wdoc = wApp.Documents.Open(fileName:=templateName, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set oRng = wdoc.content
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrWords)
        With oRng.Find
            .text = arrWords(i)
            .replacement.text = sh1.cells(r, i + 2).value
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next i

    custN = sh1.cells(r, 1).value
    wdoc.SaveAs2 fileName:=path & custN, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddtoRecentFiles:=False
    wdoc.Close False 'colse the newly created document, but keep the Word application...
    r = r + 1
 Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @user97878 Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?